# Не работает маршрутизатор в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем доброго времени суток,начал изучить Yii 2, и столкнулся в самом начале с ошибкой контроллера.
**Общий вид папок:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Контроллер:**

```
    <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

Class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionRegistr()
    {
        return $this->render('registr');
    }

    public function actionEntrance()
    {
        return $this->render('entrance');
    }
}
```

Как видно в коде,по ссылке:
test/web/index.php?r=my/index
Должен открываться файл index.php в папкe view,НО он выдает 404 ошибку.
В чем может быть проблема?
По ссылке:
http://localhost/test/web/index.php?r=site/index
Открывает дефолтную страницу Yii
Всем заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас файл без расширения php. Посмотрите сами, MyController, а должно быть MyController.php

Comment: Пля...какой же я невнимательный.Боже...
Спасибо большое)